# How to query First and Last records of every 5 seconds (or any other user-defined period) within a selected period of time in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres 9.6 table with hundreds of millions of records in 'prices' table with only four columns: uid, price, unit, dt. dt is a datetime in standard format like '2017-05-01 00:00:00.585' with fractions of a second. It might be none to dozens record each second.

I can get it by second.

```
SELECT uid, bid, ask, dt,
       CASE
           WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'First'
           WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'Last'
           ELSE 'Somwhere in the middle'
        END as Which_row_within_a_second
FROM (
   select *,
       row_number() over( partition by date_trunc('second', dt)
                          order by dt
       ) rn1,
       row_number() over( partition by date_trunc('second', dt)
                          order by dt DESC
       ) rn2       
   from prices
   where instrument = 'xxxxxx' 
         AND dt >= '2017-05-01 00:00:00'
         AND dt < '2017-05-02 00:00:00'
) xx
WHERE
    1 IN (rn1, rn2 )
ORDER BY dt
;
```

However, I need it by any period, for example 5 seconds, 1 hour, 2 hours and 30 seconds, 1 day, etc:

```
uid                                     bid     ask                             which_row_within_a_second
4ecaa607-3733-4aba-9093-abc8f59e1638    0.84331 0.8434  2017-05-01 00:00:00.031 First
cf6d5341-f7fd-47bc-89f6-a5448f78fb99    0.84329 0.84339 2017-05-01 00:00:00.943 Last
6dbf8d8e-37c8-4537-80b5-c9219f4356b1    0.8433  0.84339 2017-05-01 00:00:05.079 First
f9937464-e36a-4c57-a212-2f32943307d3    0.8433  0.84338 2017-05-01 00:00:05.83  Last
```

Attention to dt columns: it is 5 seconds interval

Also it is a bit slow and I'm looking for performance boost if possible. There is indexes on 'instrument' and combined on 'instrument, dt, bid, ask' and combined on 'dt, bid, ask'.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post some example of your expected result.

Comment: I need it like '5 seconds '::interval or '1 hours + 30 seconds', NOT 'date_trunc('second', dt)'

Comment: I've updated the question with expected output example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create the ranges on the fly based on user input, so if your range is `5 seconds`:

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '5 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:00:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-02 00:00:00'::timestamp
            , '5 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.*
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.date >= r.start_range
     AND p.date < r.end_range
), minmax as ( 
   SELECT row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt asc) as rn1,
          row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt desc) as rn2,              
          create_grp.*
   FROM create_grp 
)
SELECT uid, bid, ask, dt,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM minmax
WHERE 1 IN (rn1, rn2)
```

There is a special case when only one row for the group range.

Comment: Great one again!