# Bug in SQL query finding First and Last records per interval within a selected period of time in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Postgres 9.6.

I had been suggested [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46349485/how-to-query-first-and-last-records-of-every-5-seconds-or-any-other-user-define) which seems to work, but with all the beauty of the query, it randomly misses First or Last records. There is an example with 1 second interval for simplicity. I'm struggling to find the bugfix. Please help!

SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE public.prices
(
    uid uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    instrument character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    bid double precision NOT NULL,
    ask double precision NOT NULL,
    dt timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT prices_pkey PRIMARY KEY (uid)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

INDEXES:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_dt_instrument
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (dt, instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_dt_instrument_bid_ask
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (dt, instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default", bid, ask)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX idx_instrument
    ON public.prices USING btree
    (instrument COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

QUERY:

```
   WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '1 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:01:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-01 00:01:01'::timestamp
            , '1 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.*
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.dt >= r.start_range
     AND p.dt < r.end_range
), minmax as ( 
   SELECT row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt asc) as rn1,
          row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt desc) as rn2,              
          create_grp.*
   FROM create_grp 
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM minmax
WHERE 
    1 IN (rn1, rn2) 
    AND instrument='EURGBP'
ORDER BY dt
;
```

ORIGINAL DATASET:

```
    "uid","instrument","bid","ask","dt"
"62d857cd-4830-4146-9516-dfff57abf9de","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.057"
"da4b37f8-673e-4708-95e9-2c316b46d703","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29344","2017-05-01 00:01:00.057"
"fceb5de9-bf68-450b-91bf-b97d1af77587","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29345","2017-05-01 00:01:00.058"
"35b0113b-209d-4195-b27d-f1539055b7de","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.977997","2017-05-01 00:01:00.059"
"df347488-d5e0-4e53-b02f-88e3d63246d2","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29346","2017-05-01 00:01:00.059"
"83e5eb95-4e02-4c5d-917f-770eb232c54b","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.096"
"d4ed4f64-c292-4172-b7c9-91ee2e7e1b7b","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.979996","2017-05-01 00:01:00.132"
"d9c86d19-5f90-4afe-b29a-a3823366d700","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.981003","2017-05-01 00:01:00.143"
"830b0b6b-a520-462f-9a6d-9f0b18581ba7","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29345","2017-05-01 00:01:00.172"
"9f4a0c3b-d902-4d17-8e3d-f4867e58ed9f","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.29"
"84c303ea-777a-40c4-9d26-b0767698bda7","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.981003","2017-05-01 00:01:00.294"
"1a79250d-4c3d-47ad-9fbd-6ad208afb1fc","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.988998","2017-05-01 00:01:00.297"
"d3467ea7-0406-46c1-b95a-26fd63b7a28f","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29345","2017-05-01 00:01:00.298"
"5da4f08d-c4f8-41d3-bc55-4a0d706b872a","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.992004","2017-05-01 00:01:00.312"
"c163ff17-c7ff-4197-8858-8ebc87f1045a","GBPJPY","143.968994","143.992004","2017-05-01 00:01:00.324"
"089ee425-324b-4111-98a1-4cf8dba883c3","GBPJPY","143.968994","143.994003","2017-05-01 00:01:00.347"
"f78a9d85-485e-42ee-8d71-666238cebb02","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.994003","2017-05-01 00:01:00.357"
"c318fdb7-3503-4072-ba74-281780ac2a91","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29344","2017-05-01 00:01:00.37"
"c5a9a7b0-ee83-4d44-ba48-5f8aa82aa641","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.996002","2017-05-01 00:01:00.382"
"6c0811d3-4129-4e52-93fc-fd9f949e6459","GBPJPY","143.964996","143.996002","2017-05-01 00:01:00.484"
"eb8691da-2480-4853-b49f-ba9ee9d86086","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.485"
"0ceea454-e079-4c25-b58b-635e7c2f2e5e","GBPUSD","1.29334","1.29342","2017-05-01 00:01:00.486"
"156aeaa6-4266-4414-bf5c-400a58929a67","GBPJPY","143.968002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:00.487"
"2dc08833-8a11-4dde-907e-b4af9f795e75","GBPJPY","143.964996","143.992004","2017-05-01 00:01:00.505"
"9685ee23-3365-4db5-84da-041f1d26c6cb","EURGBP","0.8432","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.507"
"54beeda6-c693-4362-8f96-7c93fd36c4f5","GBPUSD","1.2933","1.29343","2017-05-01 00:01:00.508"
"1b09afe4-5970-43c9-9101-81be1be9c032","EURGBP","0.84321","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.519"
"40aea241-4ffe-4321-9314-b53ea5fd04d4","GBPJPY","143.964996","143.994995","2017-05-01 00:01:00.532"
"e43c2214-300b-45eb-91a7-eb4411addb06","GBPUSD","1.2933","1.2934","2017-05-01 00:01:00.54"
"fe2eaeb9-94d5-4d53-95ba-53be2864e10c","GBPJPY","143.964005","143.994995","2017-05-01 00:01:00.543"
"eacc0e09-4712-4d7c-9974-1ff4f8884a60","EURGBP","0.84322","0.84332","2017-05-01 00:01:00.553"
"7b9fda5e-dba0-4523-9f01-e7636de5ef78","GBPJPY","143.962006","143.992004","2017-05-01 00:01:00.553"
"37f5d872-1e21-4e92-bb7d-76c17e9e0278","EURGBP","0.84321","0.84332","2017-05-01 00:01:00.579"
"c7553b67-cf59-439e-ad39-ca1374d7fd81","GBPJPY","143.962006","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:00.587"
"e7addcce-55b0-4d7a-ae64-177964a6c698","GBPJPY","143.962006","143.985992","2017-05-01 00:01:00.669"
"57d8aa45-eeee-4809-91c5-9e0ff5495351","GBPUSD","1.29327","1.29341","2017-05-01 00:01:00.669"
"1c9b66f9-6558-44dd-94b7-892689ed6a8e","EURGBP","0.84321","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.67"
"f94c87b3-8dd8-4e97-8cf4-84af7e921c14","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.985992","2017-05-01 00:01:00.67"
"43fd091c-be15-476b-9e76-b9c71062ba92","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29341","2017-05-01 00:01:00.671"
"90931fdf-5507-44cb-8b25-2e06a634caad","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.672"
"a3e57590-e673-406d-9bd9-a8ac739fac37","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:00.679"
"4d2cbbec-06e3-450c-857d-97bb9a4b4271","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.833"
"4a036cce-e34a-4ec2-9bb0-5760465cd6fc","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.985992","2017-05-01 00:01:00.833"
"3ddfddb4-7c5d-4dea-92ee-411bbba4f699","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:00.834"
"2a0334b9-f6cd-4bd9-8517-7bd7cfb83415","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:00.836"
"bf9293a1-d52e-4354-9583-c3c02178f985","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.888"
"4ce95ac5-2de0-4123-8916-4dc4ab2659ea","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:00.891"
"377f5831-931b-4870-8b08-c6a7f3b6ad2e","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.014"
"96977442-9f60-4c02-87e9-c4ffa685e324","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:01.017"
"509a3f68-7126-45ea-9f89-99d92c71697a","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.017"
"14e4d804-b419-43fb-9189-44a1fbe7a4e4","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.02"
"34dd5dac-d0e1-49e5-92cf-6d9d9de14e49","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.052"
"91cdab81-8a50-4db7-8292-a90f4c8c42cb","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.065"
"e8b9b67a-3708-4463-83d9-39b0286af14e","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:01.193"
"abbb50d6-e764-48e6-9172-98dbfe04f961","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:01.195"
"d4e07afc-c0b6-45b5-9004-e378116ac8e0","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.195"
"706004b0-dc76-4dfd-ba78-f8fcf455a86b","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.196"
"a1a5c7c9-8579-4477-ba55-f3bb6f9888c7","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.231"
"5e29a0b9-e47c-4547-b9ab-30e80c50bb96","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.284"
"7fe3cea7-e2dc-4c82-b425-8cb4514a0742","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.297"
"91db0d7e-422a-4236-90f9-dbd1ca569c14","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.38"
"dfeaf1d3-adea-4476-8717-3724ffc253f4","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.403"
"378a0924-510f-41b6-aa01-0508c22f1745","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.449"
"763237fc-85ba-4263-9ab6-4348b08c5cfc","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.461"
"85a77007-c176-4ce0-9500-0d3919552fe5","EURGBP","0.84325","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.573"
"bdf1c190-d517-4b15-8b20-b01936e8e7ba","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.574"
"a80c4a57-8c3f-42f4-a6c1-54ab8f9fa13e","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.576"
"7c811f46-3772-434e-b466-ee830c62c61e","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.576"
"ec7e93ad-af3e-4d64-9c7d-5881ed6444d8","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.593"
"65f794fb-278f-40b1-9974-142b0fc03125","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.649"
"14e496ed-c732-444d-ada5-ef4e1f7434ba","GBPJPY","143.957001","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.649"
"3d28c092-3d42-4399-b774-c927c2f2283c","GBPUSD","1.29323","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.65"
"eb0bdae8-b67a-4262-ad87-0db109b53434","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.672"
"cde342f0-5bd3-469b-9f98-6053f9ea153e","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.777"
"637bec3a-c65e-49ca-8381-ab5c7df29580","GBPUSD","1.29323","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.78"
"60af62a4-524b-4ad3-a4a8-1db39a8bccf5","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.783"
"8ef15da4-7836-4186-b30b-9c4eb1e1aa3f","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.796"
"7ae9a50f-35b7-4a09-a392-1459abf12122","EURGBP","0.84327","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:01.832"
"00c63fdc-ddef-4dde-9f44-69d7482882e0","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:01.846"
"e6791f56-e321-416b-bef5-6d45f89feee0","GBPUSD","1.29323","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.946"
"7d31abc9-5ea3-4d8b-a68e-5f3c8cc6addd","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:01.95"
"ca6ac100-8fd8-46e7-afc7-9966526a5c14","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:01.96"
"5b3e48ca-b9e8-4d18-86eb-a326e33db188","GBPUSD","1.29323","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.982"
"5299b60d-654f-411a-8eab-34ed6bc61fb3","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.148"
"48dc504c-ba88-4665-a2e5-5f584529f19d","GBPUSD","1.29323","1.29338","2017-05-01 00:01:02.149"
"cafacce6-7ec1-4386-9323-6bad8d07ca50","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:02.15"
"959efc0d-6116-4c50-9a02-d3483c116732","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.151"
"097e7e31-8cb4-4f3e-9fb5-71569c5be2b7","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.187"
"18a62956-93fc-401a-9f89-8f94a3e3f463","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:02.258"
"fba787c1-db9b-4af7-80e1-8823209d30ba","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.259"
"c59d01fb-67fc-4b0d-b11a-13790ac512f5","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.356"
"13f9d5f0-f933-4633-9b79-5eaec4975997","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.357"
"e23dcfdc-1845-4c6c-b78a-c80562079853","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:02.371"
"afdf5a3a-ca4c-4b92-bbb2-f83391aaf603","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.399"
"67d58e76-34ae-4c06-b53b-dab360500f22","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.418"
"e9b1e743-2f3e-4d3e-8d01-14d7ec968efc","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.582"
"76bf9147-a9b7-4db8-bd09-4d2cd3635ace","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.796"
"4b8d5562-7bef-410d-9d83-ca5b3590aa0d","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.797"
"77849b8e-527f-47aa-967c-f4f161305537","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:02.832"
"3840acd1-c790-4302-b61d-35f76f9feb3f","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.878"
"b2786f7b-9f2c-40ae-af02-31bba7ad8ab0","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:02.987"
"0b99d3f6-1146-46ac-ba16-bc3b1f8fdf45","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:02.995"
"54cecdbd-8cee-4f77-bcc5-9fc46bd3b0e9","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:03.067"
"23c82fb7-b264-421f-b7a7-60c5f6e04065","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.09"
"564fdf6d-3a5c-46e3-8b16-51a78c08a382","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:03.091"
"df67f32a-3783-4c23-88cd-ef809dc0766b","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:03.186"
"ddb57e22-eb1f-4ba6-b442-c1bb60d3543f","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:03.208"
"8e6e2053-4aa2-4e75-8740-ea89202f727a","GBPUSD","1.29325","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.208"
"8b1ff49d-57bd-4bfd-8305-38e76ed24672","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.287"
"a65d1000-0603-4131-95b8-30c9e9c63df4","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:03.301"
"ebc03747-c019-4aa2-9fb0-36f7177546d0","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:03.389"
"abb5f2b9-869d-48d0-ab69-9d312018fdf9","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.401"
"b8a26b37-8863-497c-aafd-9ba7281e2e40","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.983994","2017-05-01 00:01:03.417"
"52fccae5-7af7-4e9d-8fb3-f9f0d8b25241","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:03.44"
"78690be1-773b-4872-a0ab-6f77c5a0a5e7","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.587"
"b3d6fd81-4c5a-49f4-896b-8b4790aa2a73","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.985001","2017-05-01 00:01:03.672"
"c9ae32fe-33d1-4486-bf79-3d23aaa42e59","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.792"
"0c005686-0b70-4d40-9dfb-913c2b4f0a01","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:03.793"
"5b8789ff-2a66-46e8-aca8-ba3f24b91cd3","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.854"
"8ee7180a-df32-4411-ab76-795148532b2f","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:03.995"
"4ef53c94-3228-42a4-a1a7-932e11df1b28","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:04.023"
"7016a0c0-297f-4299-b85b-c1cd27e7c992","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.985001","2017-05-01 00:01:04.023"
"474efc11-599d-456a-9e14-aeb906c8da8a","GBPJPY","143.955002","143.985001","2017-05-01 00:01:04.195"
"d6011bd8-4a16-40dd-9648-f401cf7d4bcb","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:04.199"
"1c8e0210-4198-4cb2-9758-73d9c68c5681","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:04.25"
"98f975ae-b410-4d00-812d-2c0f289f9ac6","GBPJPY","143.955994","143.985001","2017-05-01 00:01:04.273"
"75808e7b-be90-4284-b491-b577928e0a69","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:04.382"
"dc10ab53-1e6b-4bd2-a77e-be3fd8bf8a42","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:04.383"
"e40ab9d5-8e2e-49e5-8748-5b3c43024a6d","GBPJPY","143.955994","143.985992","2017-05-01 00:01:04.383"
"8ee41b6c-e56b-4aa0-9e79-6204cc4785a0","GBPUSD","1.29324","1.29339","2017-05-01 00:01:04.656"
```

Just as extra info with row numbers in groups. It is obviously missing rn2=1 for the first second:

```
"rn1","rn2","grp","start_range","end_range","uid","instrument","bid","ask","dt","row_position"
"1","46","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","62d857cd-4830-4146-9516-dfff57abf9de","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.057","first"
"6","42","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","83e5eb95-4e02-4c5d-917f-770eb232c54b","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.096",""
"10","38","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","9f4a0c3b-d902-4d17-8e3d-f4867e58ed9f","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.29",""
"21","27","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","eb8691da-2480-4853-b49f-ba9ee9d86086","EURGBP","0.84319","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.485",""
"25","23","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","9685ee23-3365-4db5-84da-041f1d26c6cb","EURGBP","0.8432","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.507",""
"27","21","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","1b09afe4-5970-43c9-9101-81be1be9c032","EURGBP","0.84321","0.8433","2017-05-01 00:01:00.519",""
"31","17","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","eacc0e09-4712-4d7c-9974-1ff4f8884a60","EURGBP","0.84322","0.84332","2017-05-01 00:01:00.553",""
"33","15","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","37f5d872-1e21-4e92-bb7d-76c17e9e0278","EURGBP","0.84321","0.84332","2017-05-01 00:01:00.579",""
"37","11","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","1c9b66f9-6558-44dd-94b7-892689ed6a8e","EURGBP","0.84321","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.67",""
"40","8","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","90931fdf-5507-44cb-8b25-2e06a634caad","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.672",""
"43","5","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","4d2cbbec-06e3-450c-857d-97bb9a4b4271","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.833",""
"46","2","1","2017-05-01 00:01:00","2017-05-01 00:01:01","bf9293a1-d52e-4354-9583-c3c02178f985","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:00.888",""
"2","35","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","96977442-9f60-4c02-87e9-c4ffa685e324","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:01.017",""
"7","30","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","e8b9b67a-3708-4463-83d9-39b0286af14e","EURGBP","0.84323","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:01.193",""
"9","29","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","abbb50d6-e764-48e6-9172-98dbfe04f961","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84333","2017-05-01 00:01:01.195",""
"11","26","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","a1a5c7c9-8579-4477-ba55-f3bb6f9888c7","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.231",""
"14","23","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","91db0d7e-422a-4236-90f9-dbd1ca569c14","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.38",""
"17","20","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","763237fc-85ba-4263-9ab6-4348b08c5cfc","EURGBP","0.84324","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.461",""
"18","19","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","85a77007-c176-4ce0-9500-0d3919552fe5","EURGBP","0.84325","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.573",""
"20","17","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","a80c4a57-8c3f-42f4-a6c1-54ab8f9fa13e","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84334","2017-05-01 00:01:01.576",""
"23","14","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","65f794fb-278f-40b1-9974-142b0fc03125","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.649",""
"27","10","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","cde342f0-5bd3-469b-9f98-6053f9ea153e","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84338","2017-05-01 00:01:01.777",""
"29","8","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","60af62a4-524b-4ad3-a4a8-1db39a8bccf5","EURGBP","0.84327","0.84339","2017-05-01 00:01:01.783",""
"31","6","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","7ae9a50f-35b7-4a09-a392-1459abf12122","EURGBP","0.84327","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:01.832",""
"32","5","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","00c63fdc-ddef-4dde-9f44-69d7482882e0","EURGBP","0.84328","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:01.846",""
"35","2","2","2017-05-01 00:01:01","2017-05-01 00:01:02","ca6ac100-8fd8-46e7-afc7-9966526a5c14","EURGBP","0.84329","0.8434","2017-05-01 00:01:01.96",""
```

Is it some kind of Postgres bug?

Any ideas how to fix it are very welcome!

Comment: If you remove ' 1 IN (rn1, rn2) AND ' from the last WHERE clause, you can see that query does pick up the last record to mark it as last. So either 'row_number() over (partition by grp order by dt desc) as rn2' does not execute always or  'WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last' is not executed. in any way I find it bizzar as it work most of records, but not all of them!

Comment: Note: your sample data only contains the first second of minute one: `2017-05-01 00:01:00`

Comment: @uzla  on my db your query returns correctly first and last row_position (rn1=1 and rn2=1)

Comment: hm. I've added full output where it is clear that rn2=1 is missing in first second... what version of Postgres do you have? (i've tried restarting postgres just in case of some odd caching issues, etc, but as expected no luck...)

Comment: @uzla I am trying on rextester (version 9.6).  See UZLA - FIND FIRST AND LAST RECORDS PER INTERVAL - http://rextester.com/WTDG26956

Comment: @uzla in demo on rextester I added  last four records to try with other dt

Comment: You are right . the dataset was flowed. it only had one instrument. Sorry. I have update it.

Comment: I Found that if I move " instrument='EURGBP' " from last WHERE to create_grp ust after JOIN stuff, it works, BUT extremely slowwww. It looks like it does not use index within group or something.... and if WHERE left where it is, it does not pick up rn2 when rn2=1 belongs to the record with different instrument. So, the landscape changes to performance when moving WHERE clause... if I'm not clear, please, ask me to re-phrase! :-)

Comment: The slowness is exactly the reason why I avoided the CTE and the generate_series().

Comment: @uzla: I don't see the dataset updated.  Am I wrong?

Comment: @esla: my apologies. I was on the move, so it did not uploaded. just fixed it and new data set is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar query without the CTE and the calendar-seconds:

---

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM (
    SELECT p.uid, p.instrument, date_trunc('second', p.dt) AS the_second , p.dt AS dt, p.bid, p.ask
        , row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('second', p.dt) order by dt asc) as rn1
        , row_number() over (partition by date_trunc('second', p.dt) order by dt desc) as rn2
    FROM prices p
        )minmax
WHERE instrument='EURGBP'
AND (rn1=1 OR rn2=1)
ORDER BY dt
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks, BUT this doesn't work. It must be intervals, as mentioned I specifically set to 1sec Only for simplicity of examples... Sorry.

Comment: Yes it does work. within the scope of your question.

Comment: joop, I appreciate y effort, but the title says: PER INTERVAL within a selected period of time in postgres... and the  question description says that 'There is an example with 1 second interval FOR SIMPLICITY'.. it won't work for 5 seconds or 1,5 days... I need to admit, that your query works really fast, but useless in the scope of the problem as it only covers minor custom case and does not meet the question in full.

Comment: And to adapt to the changed data in the question, you could move the `where` clause to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

This query below works. The problem was in WHERE clause location . It must be within groups, otherwise row numbers become impacted by other instruments.

```
WITH ranges as (
    SELECT dd as start_range, 
           dd + '1 seconds'::interval as end_range, 
           ROW_NUMBER() over () as grp
    FROM generate_series
            ( '2017-05-01 00:01:00'::timestamp 
            , '2017-05-01 00:01:00'::timestamp
            , '1 seconds'::interval) dd
), create_grp as (
    SELECT r.grp, r.start_range, r.end_range, p.*
    FROM prices p
    JOIN ranges r
      ON p.dt >= r.start_range
      AND p.dt < r.end_range
-- WHERE moves here from the end of the query
    WHERE instrument='EURGBP'
), minmax as ( 
   SELECT row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt asc) as rn1,
          row_number() over (partition by grp
                             order by dt desc) as rn2,              
          create_grp.*
   FROM create_grp 
)
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN rn1 = 1 and rn2 = 1 THEN 'first and last'
            WHEN rn1 = 1 THEN 'first'
            WHEN rn2 = 1 THEN 'last'
       END as row_position
FROM minmax
WHERE 
    1 IN (rn1, rn2) 
--    AND instrument='EURGBP'
ORDER BY dt
;
```

The the problem solved, but it raises new one: such change to query make is to run very slow! despite of the index on instruments. I'm raising new question about it and linking it here.